# How to handle 'this' in typescript/js ? need to convert Python code to Typescript

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, typescript, this

I have this simple code written in python to create a small
Cards game and I want to make the same using typescript but I'm
facing a big problem with 'this' in my main class in Typescript
this is the original python class:

```
class deck:
    card_type=['Hearts ','Diamonds','Spades','Clubs']
    card_rank=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'A','J','Q','K']
    full_deck=[]

    def build_deck(self):
        single={}
        for card in self.card_type:
            for n in self.card_rank:
                single={n: card}
                self.full_deck.append(single)
        shuffle(self.full_deck)


    def reshuffle (self):
        print('Re-shuffling again!')
        shuffle(self.full_deck)


    def choose_card(self):
        chosen=choice(self.full_deck)
        the_index= self.full_deck.index(chosen)
        self.full_deck.pop(the_index)

        return chosen

    def pick_hand(self, number_of_cards):
        hand=[]
        new_card={}

        for i in range(number_of_cards):
            new_card = self.choose_card()
            hand.append(new_card)

        return hand
```

And in my main game file I do something like this:

```
from classes import deck

deck1= deck()
deck1.build_deck()
my_hand=deck1.pick_hand(3)
compu_hand=deck1.pick_hand(3)
```

---

But when I try to create a similar class in type script I wrote the following:

```
export class deck {

  single_card: {
    cType: string;
    cNumber: any;
  };

  fullDeck: any[] = [];
  card_type=['Hearts ','Diamonds','Spades','Clubs'];
  card_rank=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'A','J','Q','K'];

  shuffle() {
    let counter = this.fullDeck.length;

    // While there are elements in the array
    while (counter > 0) {
        // Pick a random index
        let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

        // Decrease counter by 1
        counter--;

        // And swap the last element with it
        let temp = this.fullDeck[counter];
        this.fullDeck[counter] = this.fullDeck[index];
        this.fullDeck[index] = temp;
    }

    // return this.fullDeck;
  }


  buildDeck (){

    for (let t in this.card_type) {
      for ( let n in this.card_rank) {
        this.single_card.cType = this.card_type[t];
        this.single_card.cNumber = this.card_rank[n];
        this.fullDeck.push(this.single_card);
        console.log(this.single_card);
      }
    }
    // this.shuffle() 

  }

}
```

When I try to use the class from the main 'ts' file like so:

```
import {deck} from './myclasses'

$(document).ready (function(){
    let deck1= new deck;
    deck1.buildDeck();
});
```

The console.log call returns the same error :

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot set property 'cType' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot set property 'cType' of undefined
>       at deck.buildDeck (file:///run/media/Work/HTML_Porjects/Game_TS/built/myclasses.js:132:44)

**How is it undefined?** 
**What do I need to do to make the Typescript code work like the Python code?**

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Apologies, I gave an answer that I think _may have been_ wildly wrong.

Comment: But it does seem like you're using `single_card` oddly. Are you not defining it as a datatype? Why is is then being used like an object property?

Comment: Thanks for the response and I did try the arrow function it does not work

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean? single_card is property of the deck class

Comment: Doesn't look like it. It's not showing up in `this` like all the other properties. There has to be something syntactically incorrect with it. But I don't know typescript ;)

Answer (score 2):

The error simply states that `single_card` is undefined, which it is:

```
class deck {

  single_card: {
    cType: string;
    cNumber: any;
  };

  // …
}
```

This will declare the property `single_card` on the TypeScript class, so that the compiler will accept when you refer to the `single_card` property of an object of that type (e.g. when doing `this.single_card`). However, doing so will *not* actually assign an object of that type to the object. So for the compiled JavaScript (where type information is removed), that property does not exist since you never assign to it. You can easily verify that by looking at the [compiled JavaScript there](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20deck%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20single_card%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cType%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cNumber%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20fullDeck%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20card_type%3D%5B'Hearts%20'%2C'Diamonds'%2C'Spades'%2C'Clubs'%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20card_rank%3D%5B2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C'A'%2C'J'%2C'Q'%2C'K'%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20shuffle%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20counter%20%3D%20this.fullDeck.length%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20While%20there%20are%20elements%20in%20the%20array%0D%0A%20%20%20%20while%20%28counter%20%3E%200%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Pick%20a%20random%20index%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20index%20%3D%20Math.floor%28Math.random%28%29%20*%20counter%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Decrease%20counter%20by%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20counter--%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20And%20swap%20the%20last%20element%20with%20it%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20temp%20%3D%20this.fullDeck%5Bcounter%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.fullDeck%5Bcounter%5D%20%3D%20this.fullDeck%5Bindex%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.fullDeck%5Bindex%5D%20%3D%20temp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20return%20this.fullDeck%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20buildDeck%20%28%29%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20%28let%20t%20in%20this.card_type%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20%28%20let%20n%20in%20this.card_rank%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.single_card.cType%20%3D%20this.card_type%5Bt%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.single_card.cNumber%20%3D%20this.card_rank%5Bn%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.fullDeck.push%28this.single_card%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%28this.single_card%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20this.shuffle%28%29%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20deck1%3D%20new%20deck%3B%0D%0Adeck1.buildDeck%28%29%3B).

So what you would need to do first is assign something to `single_card` just like you did in the Python version:

```
this.single_card = {}
```

However, if you actually look at your Python version, `single_card` is not a member of the object and it actually doesn’t make any sense for it to be. You are using that to construct the card object you are then adding to the `fullDeck` array. In Python, it is a local variable, so you should make it a local variable in the TypeScript version too:

```
buildDeck() {
  for (const t of this.card_type) {
    for (const n of this.card_rank) {
      const single_card = {
          cType: this.card_type[t],
          cNumber: this.card_rank[n]
      };
      this.fullDeck.push(single_card);
    }
  }
}
```

Btw. you also want to use a `for…of` loop there instead of `for…in`.

You should also think about making `fullDeck` properly typed. Right now it is an array of `any`, so it can store any object. But what you want to do is actually just keep objects in there that look the way `single_card` looks. So consider declaring a type for this:

```
interface SingleCard {
    cType: string;
    cNumber: any;
}
```

Then, you can properly type `fullDeck`:

```
fullDeck: SingleCard[] = [];
```

Comment: Your answer was what I was pretty much thinking was happening, but lack the knowledge to know the actual TS syntax. Nice answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer, and I agree with you that single_card should not be a member of the object and it was not but during my failed tries I moved it inside but now I moved it out. As for your advice it actually fixed the error but for some reason full_deck  is 52 item of the last card! 52 copy of the same object! when I try to console.log the object single_card inside the loop I get 52 different cards but the list full_deck is populated with the last card only! why is this happening?

Comment: If you keep pushing the same `single_card` object, and just update its properties, then all objects will be the same. You should create a new object in every iteration like I showed in my answer (Or at least do `single_card = {}` before assigning its properties).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked finally ... I hate JS and Typescript btw!

Comment: That’s not JS/TS specific though, you would have hit the exact same problem if you used an instance member in the Python solution ;)